# DRY vs appropriate separation of concerns

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, dry, separation-of-concerns

I have a situation where a different background image is rendered based on the `@page_name` variable. It seems to me like I could either do something like this in the HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path "Jumbotron/#{@page_name}.gif" %>)">
```

Which would be the DRYest, or I could actually use the CSS file and do something like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron <%= @page_name %>">

.jumbotron.home {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path "Jumbotron/home.gif" %>);
}

.jumbotron.outdoors {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path "Jumbotron/outdoors.gif" %>);
}

.jumbotron.snowsports {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path "Jumbotron/snowsports.gif" %>);
}
```

Which would be separating the concerns but less DRY.

Any thoughts on what is more optimal? E.g., from a speed & performance perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a real performance difference here. There are several reasons against using `style` attributes in your DOM - every SEO analysis tool out there will raise a warning flag and discourage you.

I'd just go for the the [Principle Of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) here and handle the style where it naturally belongs, in your CSS.

Only if there are **many** of those images depending on the path name, or if they are user-entered, I'd go for the first option.

But this is just my opinion.